# In Twilio Programmable Chat, in Laravel PHP, how to get all channels that a user belongs to?

Tags: laravel, twilio, channel, twilio-programmable-chat

I use Laravel PHP, and I tried this:

```
$ucs = $twilio->chat->v2->services($this->serviceId)
            ->users($username)
            ->userChannels
            ->read(50);
```

but it seems to be getting only the channels that user has created, not including the ones where he is in the channel, but hasn't created the channel. How do I get all the channels where this user is in?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[The documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/user-channel-resource) says that:

> The User Channel resource of Programmable Chat is a read-only resource that describes a Channel that the User is a Member of.

When you read the [properties of a User Channel](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/user-channel-resource#userchannel-properties), you should find the `status` property which will tell you whether they have `joined`, been `invited` or are `not_participating`.

So, the User Channels resource should indeed return the channels a user is a member of.

If you are finding that the API request is not returning what the documentation describes, I would recommend getting in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) who can help you raise this.

One final point, I've noticed you're asking about Twilio Chat a few times. Twilio Chat is to be sunset on July 25, 2022 so that we can focus on the next generation chat powered by the [Twilio Conversations API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations). There is a [migration guide for upgrading from Chat to Conversations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/migrating-chat-conversations) and I recommend that you try to use Conversations going forward.